# Is it possible to roll back from wordpress 3.7 to 3.6?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, rollback

I just upgrade my wordpress to version 3.7 and thus all my pages redirect to 404.php I search stackoverflow to solve it's problem but I can't do it.

then I decide to roll back to edition 3.6 how can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: only stackoverflow not google ?

Comment: Update your permalinks.  See if that does anything for the 404's.  Otherwise, if you absolutely think you need to roll back versions, you can find all previous versions here: http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/.